# What happens when I don't write accessor methods for Core Data scalar property?

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I am working with several Core Data entities that I used to generate NSManagedObject subclasses, and at the time I generated those classes I selected the "Use scalar properties for primitive data types" option. As expected, integer attributes were declared as `int16_t` properties and floating point attributes were declared as `float` properties in the generated interface:

```
@interface TeamStats:NSManagedObject
@property (nonatomic) int16_t pointsScored;
@property (nonatomic) float winPercentage;
@end
```

In the generated implementation for this interface, I see these properties declared with `@dynamic`:

```
@implementation TeamStats
@dynamic pointsScored;
@dynamic winPercentage;
@end
```

Now, according to the Core Data documentation, I should need to write accessor methods for these scalar properties because Core Data cannot generate them for me:

> You can declare properties as scalar values, but for scalar values Core Data cannot 
>   dynamically generate accessor methods—you must provide your own implementations (see 
>   “Managed Object Accessor Methods” (page 44)). Core Data automatically synthesizes the 
>   primitive accessor methods (primitiveLength and setPrimitiveLength:), but you need to 
>   declare them to suppress compiler warnings.

This all makes sense, and I can see numerous SO posts asking about how these accessor methods should be written, with lots of good answers.

What I can't figure out is this: I wrote this code and started using it before I ever read this detail in the documentation, so I never wrote any accessor methods. I just have the @dynamic declarations in my class implementation. Despite not having written the accessor methods I should need, the code appears to work just fine. I have created instances of this NSManagedObject subclass. I have send instances of this class a `setPointsScored:` and a `pointsScored` message, and saved the resulting instance to its persistence store. Everything seems to work.

What am I missing here? Are there default implementations that are getting generated, despite what the Core Data documentation says? Are there going to be situations where my current code doesn't work that I need to be aware of? I would love to understand what is happening here before coding more NSManagedObject subclasses...

Comment: Uh... I don't write these either... I think CoreData actually takes care of creating them for you now?

Comment: it does nowadays, the docs are wrong

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Creating scalar accessors for primitive data types is a feature introduced with Xcode 4, but obviously not well-documented. It is mentioned in the WWDC 2011 Session videos

- "303 What's New in Core Data on iOS" (slide 95)
- "315 What's New in Core Data on Mac OS X" (slide 90)

According to the information from these sessions, the scalar accessors avoid the overhead of constructing `NSNumber` objects, so they are more efficient than the implementations shown in the "Core Data Programming Guide".

So to answer your question: Default accessors for the scalar properties are automatically generated. The "Core Data Programming Guide" is outdated with respect to this feature.

Comment: Thanks for the reference, Martin - It seemed likely that the documentation was outdated but it is comforting to know that the change was at least mentioned somewhere by Apple.