# CoreData convert NSNumbers to BOOL

Tags: ios, core-data

I have an entity in my CoreData model which has a boolean field.  This is stored on the CoreData Entity as an `NSNumber`.  What I'd like is for the accessors to use `BOOL` and not `NSNumber`, so I can use

```
comment.isActive = YES;
```

instead of:

```
BOOL isCommentActive = [NSNumber numberWithBool:comment.isActive];
```

I was going to change the code in the auto-generated entity class file, but I was told not to do this since it overwrites each time I extract the model.

I have a category for the entity, and I tried coding an accessor which converts it to a `BOOL` of the same name, but this just resulted in me getting stuck into a loop.

Some people have mentioned method twizzling, but it sounds pretty hacky to me.  Should i just create an accessor which returns a primitive of a different name?

Comment: Now I believe that you can use `comment.isActive = @YES;`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just choose the option "Use scalar properties for primitive data types" when creating
the managed object subclasses in Xcode. This will create the property

```
@interface MyEntity : NSManagedObject
@property (nonatomic) BOOL active;
@end
```

and all conversions are done automatically "under the hood". It is actually more
efficient, because no `NSNumber` objects are created.

Unfortunately, the "Core Data Programming Guide" is outdated with respect
to this, [it still claims](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdNSAttributes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001919-SW13):

> You can declare properties as scalar values, but for scalar values
>   Core Data cannot dynamically generate accessor methods—you must
>   provide your own implementations.

The only Apple "documentation" that I know of is the WWDC 2011 sessions videos, compare https://stackoverflow.com/a/14091193/1187415.

Comment: Martin for president!  Thank you!

Comment: I sent bug report to Apple

Comment: So, using primitive data types means I have to use NSTimeInterval instead of NSDate.  Interesting.  If I want to continue using NSDate, would I need to write additional accessors (like getDate and setDate)?

Comment: @theDuncs: That is probably the cleanest way.

Comment: @theDuncs: you can actually just change the type of the property to NSDate* in the header file, and leave it as dynamic in the .m file. The only drawback is that Xcode will overwrite this when you generate the files again.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Martin but you can try adding this function in your existing NSManagedObject subclass:

```
 -(void)setActiveRaw:(BOOL)active
 {
     [self setActive:[NSNumber numberWithBool:active]];
 }
```

And use it like this:

```
 [comment setActiveRaw:YES];
```

instead of

```
 comment.active = [NSNumber numberWithBool:comment.isActive];
```

And you can write a getter for this too:

```
 -(BOOL)getActiveRaw
 { 
    return [self.active boolValue]
 }
```

Comment: Thanks so much.  This doesn't help so much when I want to get the value, but you're right about the setting. Thanks.

Comment: No problem let me put the getter function for ya.

Comment: OK, but that's renaming the property, which I didn't want to do.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: It is not exactly renaming, we are just writing a custom getter and a setter to work with the core data values (NSNumber type) by talking values we know (BOOL type). And I am 100 percent sure I am not renaming property, I use this for storing typeDef type properties in core data.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say that what I wanted was a pair of accessors the same name as the attribute on the CoreData entity.  Martin's answer works great for me. Thanks!